# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.lib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am encountering an error when using pandas.

```
in <module>
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 from matplotlib.dates import drange, date2num
----> 3 from pandas.lib import Timestamp
      4 from datetime import timedelta
      5 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.lib'
```

How can I fix this error?

I use Python 3.8

Comment: `from pandas import Timestamp`? or why not just `import pandas as pd`, then `pd.Timestamp`, which seems to be more customary

Comment: I am trying to use a ggplot library that uses other libraries: https://pypi.org/project/ggplot/0.4.7/

Answer (score 0):

May 5, 2017 in `pd.__version__ == '0.21.1'` [pandas moved around and deprecated a bunch of modules](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#reorganization-of-the-library-privacy-changes)

```
Previous Location       New Location   Deprecated
       pandas.lib   pandas._libs.lib            X
```

The `ggplot` version you reference was released in 2014 and hasn't been maintained since 2016 so there are bound to be issues with newer versions of pandas. If you insist on using a package that hasn't kept up with the `pandas` development, you'll need to install a much older version of pandas, something before `0.21.1`